# Capturing 3d object with its Background view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am new in Open GLES.
I got stuck at capturing the 3d object with its Background image.
I am adding the  CAEAGLLayer view as subview in my view
and i am able to take the image of 3d object but it is coming with black background but i want to take the image of whole view on which i am showing my 3d object.
So please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[iPhone\] OpenGL transparent background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193607/iphone-opengl-transparent-background)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information. What is the background?

- You use 1 view, it is `EAGLView` the I guess you should get the correct result.
- You use EAGLView as subview of your `background` then you need to capture 2 images then combine them into one.

Call `[CALayer drawInContext:viewContext]` to get image of your `background` view.

Combine 2 images

```
+ (UIImage *) imageFromImage:(UIImage *)img1 andImage:(UIImage*) img2 {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img1.size);
[img1 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[img2 drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I am adding the  CAEAGLLayer view as subview in my view
and i am able to take the image of 3d object but it is coming with black background but i want to take the image of whole view on which i am showing my 3d object.