# XCODE 5 iOS7 how to convert UIImage (PNG) to NSData without losing the transparent background

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, ios7, uiimagepngrepresentation

i have a method that receives a `UIImage` I convert it to `NSData` and make a request to post that Data, it works on iOS 6 but when i try on iOS 7, the image lose the transparent background.

this is what i have tried till now:

```
-(void)post:(UIImage *)firm name:
{

    int x = 350;

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(firm);
    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, x, 40, 50)];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    imageView.image = image;


    NSData *imageData2 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(firm)];
    UIImage *image2=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData2];
    UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, x, 40, 50)];
    imageView2.image = image2;

    UIImageView *imageView3 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, x, 40, 50)];
    imageView3.image = firm;

    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
    UIImageView *imageView4 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, x, 40, 50)];
    imageView4.image = img;

    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView2];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView3];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView4];
```

on the the `imageView3` i'm just showing it as i get it without background (till here i get it all fine) but when i convert to `NSData` an then get it back to `UIImage` it loses the transparency,

code running on iOS 7

[image]

Same code running on iOS 6 and below works perfect!!

[image]

i have created an example os my issue on [Github example](http://github.com/fiigo0/signView)

Comment: BTW, [responding to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19108457/cgimagecreatewithmaskingcolors-doesnt-work-with-ios7), I noticed that someone else was having a problem with `CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors` not preserving the alpha channel in iOS 7 in conjunction with `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. In my final solution below, I coincidentally removed the call to `CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors` as I streamlined your OpenGL code. Bottom line, I suspect you stumbled across an actual iOS 7 bug with `CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors` and it sounds like we've got a couple work-arounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` on an image with transparency on iOS7, the transparency is preserved.

For example, using this image:

[image: stroke]

When I render that using your code, I get:

[image]

Perhaps there's something about the image that you started with.

---

The issue seems to stem from the OpenGLES code that created the image. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4456862/1271826), it appears that you need to use

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
```

instead of

```
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
```

I also used the `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` value for `CGBitmapInfo`.

Doing all of that, rendered the call to `CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors` unnecessary, and the resulting image appears to be correctly preserves the alpha channel when you call `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Comment: Hi Rob, i have tried on the first UIImage view that i created imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; and i just double check your answer adding the same backgroundColor for each uiimageview but no luck. Thank you for your response!

Comment: im using https://github.com/jcmontiel/SignatureView/blob/master/SignatureView.m this library to generate the image on the method "- (UIImage *) getSignatureImage", i have check the code with your image and its working fine, but for some reason with the image generated it does not.

Comment: @fiigo0 I'm not an OpenGLES guy, so I'm not sure why that's not rendering the transparent background correctly. But the line `eaglLayer.opaque = YES;` looks highly suspect. I'd suggest trying `NO`, which is the typical answer for OpenGLES background transparency. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4456862/1271826).

Comment: As an aside, I did a quick test creating a path using CoreGraphics' `CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);` and the resulting image had the correct transparent background. I'm sure if you used a `CAShapeLayer`, that would work, too. (BTW, both CoreGraphics and `CAShapeLayer` strike me as easier ways to draw simple line paths.)

Comment: i have tried eaglLayer.opaque = NO i forgot to mention that change that solved transparency for ios6, ill take a look at CoreGraphics as you mention, i really appreciate your time and your help!

Comment: Hi again Rob, about what you mention to get the transparent background on iOS 6 i had to set eaglLayer.opaque = NO also create the image with a mask on the SignatureView.m on method getSignatureImage.

Comment: Hi Rob, the issue is SOLVED! form some reason on iOS7 the value of the bitsPerComponent has to be 1 (not sure why) so adding the following code on getSignatureImage method solved the transparent issue on iOS7                            int bitsPerComponent;
    // prep the ingredients
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)
    {
        bitsPerComponent = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        bitsPerComponent = 8;
    }

Comment: @fiigo0 That's great if that works (though, I confess, it seems strange). I also sent you a pull request that includes another solution, that I came up with.

Comment: yes i just saw your mail i'll check your code! thank you for your time and patience!