# No transparency on OpenglES layer on iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, ios-simulator

On my IOS application, I have a screen with 2 views : one classic UIView and one openGLES view. 
The 3d view is over the 2d and I set a clear background to see the 2d view behind it.

it is displayed as expected on all ios devices but the 3d view is opaque on ios simulator.
On the 3DView I use these lines :

```
[myOpenGLView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[myOpenGLView setOpaque:NO];
```

And before each render I call :

```
glClearColor(0.,0.,0.,0.);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Does anybody got the same problem ?

Comment: Have you followed all the steps here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4456862/19679 ? Note that you'll want to work with the CAEAGLLayer that backs your view, not the view itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I can't change the opacity of the eaglLayer.

My opengl view is a singleton, when I initialize it I call

```
eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
```

and when I use it for the second time (where I need transparency) I change its value NO but the layer is black on simulator and translucent on iOS devices.

On the other hand if I set the opacity to NO directly, I don't have the bug on simulator